# How to scrape the contents of attributes in list of links (HTML)

Tags: html, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the building names, addresses, etc from [this website](http://www.concordia.ca/maps/sgw-campus.html).

I have tried using tools such as [import.io](https://import.io/), [Webharvey](https://www.webharvy.com/) and others but the issue is that it only allows me to scrape the text in the link tag.

Below is a sample of the source code of the relevant section I want to work with. What I would like is a way to scrape the text but also the 'data-original-title', 'the data content' and other attribute data.

```
 <div class="container">
    <ul class="c-buildingbar">
        <li><span>Buildings:</span></li>
            <li><a class="acc" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Pavillon Des Soeurs Grises" data-content="1190 Guy Street" href="?building="></a></li>
            <li><a class="acc" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-original-title="B Building" data-content="2160 Bishop" href="?building=B">B</a></li>
...
</div>
```

Comment: I can easily provide you with the XPath for it, but what language are you using? Sure there are good solutions for Ruby, Pythin and Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont normally work in C# but this should do the trick for you:

```
{
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load ("http://www.concordia.ca/maps/sgw-campus.html");

    foreach (HtmlNode row in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//li[contains(@class,'acc')]/a")) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(row.SelectSingleNode("/@data-original-title").Value);
        Console.WriteLine(row.SelectSingleNode("/@data-content").Value);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Although I can't test it myself this should give you something to work with :)